# How to Scroll Horizontal Bootstrap Tabs In Smaller Increments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to scroll through my horizontal Bootstrap tabs, however, the scroller goes all the way to the end of the tab list, making some tabs not even visible. So is there a way to incrementally scroll through the tabs until you get to a certain point? (then I'd be fine with it scrolling to the end).

I've googled this subject quite a bit, and all the examples seem to go right to the end of the tablist.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/82c4ged0/

```js
$('.scroller-right').click(function() {
  
  $('.scroller-left').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.scroller-right').fadeOut('slow');
  
  $('.list').animate({left:"+="+widthOfHidden()+"px"},'slow',function(){
  });
});

$('.scroller-left').click(function() {
  
  $('.scroller-right').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.scroller-left').fadeOut('slow');
  
    $('.list').animate({left:"-="+getLeftPosi()+"px"},'slow',function(){
    });
});
```

In the fiddle, with the much smaller window, it's much clearer to see how the scroller goes straight to the last tabs in the list

Answer (score 0):

The way things are currently setup, you're getting the amount to scroll with this variable/function.

`var widthOfHidden = function(){
  return (($('.wrapper').outerWidth())-widthOfList()-getLeftPosi());
};`

You'll need to calculate how many pixels to move over on each click. It's roughly -220px which you can put in manually to try it out. You can put that in manually, like below, and see if things behave close to how you want them to.

`var widthOfHidden = function(){
  return -224;
};`